# I have issues with my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't what happen with my script can i please point out where is my mistake. 1 to 9 all condition working fine but when you put 10-12 is not work

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
<input type="hidden" value="2" id="itemstock" name="itemstock">
<input value="1" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="text">
<button type="submit" onClick="return checkoption();" >Click </button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function checkoption()
{
    var itemqty = document.getElementById('quantity');
    var iss = document.getElementById('itemstock');

    if(itemqty.value > iss.value)
    {
        alert('We have Currently '+iss.value+' In Stock');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('add to cart'); 
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Screen short see qty i put 13 but its not showing error

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What does it do? Why is it wrong? Consider setting up a jsfiddle as an example.

Comment: Protip: element values are stored as strings, meaning you should convert to `int` or `float`!

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything..

Comment: Second Protip: inline event handling is bad practice. You should use an external event listener (see `addEventListener`)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, or the problem is not clear: http://jsfiddle.net/P8G3V/

Comment: you do not cancel the form submission.

Comment: Third Protip: Your function does not return a boolean, which it expects.

Third.5 Protip: `alert` is not a debugging tool

Comment: i Put 13 in textbox its should give error "We have Currently 2 In Stock"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `<` or `>` operators with strings will compare the values alphabetically, which is probably not what you want.

You need to compare these as numbers, not as strings.  JavaScript allows you to easily *cast* a string to a number using `+`, like so:

```
var qty = +itemqty.value;
var isv = +iss.value;

if(qty > isv)
{
  // ...
}
```

However, you can also use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (which will return NaN if the value is invalid) if you want to add more error checking in your code.

Comment: You should mention that using the operator `+` before a variable performs a type conversion

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Thanks!  I've improved my answer.

Comment: Have a +1 sir! (Although there are so many technical issues in the OP code I'm not even sure it should be answered until it less-broadens)

Answer (score 0):

The `.value` attribute on a text field such as `input` is a string, not a number. Therefore, you compare strings lexicographically. Change them into numbers, either via `parseInt(str, 10)` or via `+str`.